# update prices in text after deleting items from button in inner html

Tags: javascript, jquery

The div tags are created inside this const and I have used a delete function to delete items from order page. I want to update prices after deletion and updating in text displaying totalprice.

```js
total_price = total_price + parseInt(item.prisinklmoms);

// Create a row for the item in view
const order_item = document.createElement('div');
order_item.className = `ordered_item`;
order_item.innerHTML = `<div class="product-name">${item.namn}</div>
                            <div class="product-percentage">${item.alkoholhalt}</div>
                            <div class="product-price">${item.prisinklmoms}</div>
                            <button id="div-button"  onclick="delOrderlist(this)">Del</button>`;
orderContainer.appendChild(order_item);
```

Comment: I am using delete function Ö

Comment: // Delete the list of order
const delOrderlist = (orders) => {
 orders.parentElement.remove();
 //update price of items deleted
 $('#total_val').text(${item.prisinklmoms});
};

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: total_price is not defined`

Comment: Please update your snippet with relevant HTML in a [mcve]

Comment: I suggest you delegate after changing the ID to CLASS (IDs need to be unique) : `orderContainer.on("click",".div-button",function() {delOrderlist(this)})`